# Saving an image from chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart control and I want to save the chart after it is drawn.
I have a problem probably it's in the path that I want to save the image in but I'm not sure.

Here's the code:

```
string dir = $"{System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\Charts\\{DateTime.Now.ToString()}.png";
chart1.SaveImage(dir, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

This directory is: "C:\Users\Hendawi\Desktop\ESI-USB-API\Examples\C#\bin\Debug\Charts\2023-04-03 5:18:41 PM.png"

The error I get is: System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'

If I try to save the file on the desktop for example, it works. I don't know what is wrong with my path.

Edit (Solved):
Thanks to @DanielA.White. Colons that are generated in Datetime.Now() aren't supported in naming files in windows

Comment: colons are not supported file names on windows

Comment: @DanielA.White Wow I don't know how I missed that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `DateTime.ToString()` by default is likely to include characters (depending on your locale) that are not valid in filenames, like '/' and ':'.

Ordinarily you would use a [Standard date and time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or a [Custom date and time format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) in a `String.Format()` or [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) to use the current date to construct a compatible file name:

```
string dir = $"{System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\Charts\\{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.png";
chart1.SaveImage(dir, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

This would result in

```
"C:\Users\Hendawi\Desktop\ESI-USB-API\Examples\C#\bin\Debug\Charts\20230403_171841.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical `DateTime.Now.ToString()` will have a colon/forward slash included in the time format. For example: `4/3/2023 3:35:45 PM`
This is not a [valid file name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=net-8.0).

You could easily write an extension that support a file friendly date time:

```
public static string ToFileNameFriendly(this DateTime val)
        {
            return $"{val.Year}_{val.Month}_{val.Day}_{val.Hour}_{val.Minute}_{val.Second}_{val.Millisecond}";
        }
```

Comment: this is a bit overkill when there is a standard solution for this built into the framework. There are times when resorting to an extension method is valid however we want to encourage the community to use the standards built into the framework as the first response.